# Who is responsible for setting the object properties?

Tags: java

I have an object with fields.
In a project I need this object filled with information.

whose responsibility is to fill this object?

I would like a method like getFilledObject() that returns a full filled object to my program.

I can put this logic into the main flow, and fill it "in place", also I can add this method into the class itself, so that it would know how to fill itself according to the parameters I pass.
The latter decision is good enough, the only problem is that the class must then know much more about it's nature than a simple plain get-set class.

But I feel neither decision is good enough. What should it be? A helper class that contains only the logic to fill the object?

---

You know, yes, Factory is what I was looking for, but it is always mentioned along with polymorphism. In my case I don't need it at all. So I can call it a factory, but would it really be what they called "A Factory pattern"?

So what do we have as a result?
first, static factory method

```
class A {
ObjType1 obj1;
ObjType2 obj2;

public A() {}

public static getA(int param1, int param2) {
  A a = null;
  ObjType3 obj3 = null; 
  if (somelib.complexCheck(param)) {
    obj3 = someotherlib.getSomething(param2);
    // other stuff
  }
  if (obj3 != null) {
    // do something with getters & setters, fill a
  }
  return a;
}
```

and Factory pattern or something similar to it

```
class Fact {
 public static A getA(int param1, int param2) {
   // do all that stuff here
 }
}
```

the difference in my opinion would be lots of import directives in the A class in case of *static factory method* . Also, we can put similar static methods into the Fact class if all those need the same libraries.

What would you choose between the two?

Comment: "problem is that the class must then know much more about it's nature than a simple plain get-set class"  This is a "problem"?  Really?  What are you talking about?  How -- exactly -- is this a problem?  This sounds like the essential definition of an class: it has all of the responsibility and knowledge in one place.  What "problem" are you talking about?  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: ok, let's say I must check whether the object I'm looking for is in HttpSession. If so, I can check whether it is fine or corrupted. Then if it's not there, I must query the database and construct a complex object and then return a reference to it. I feel that decoupling of getters/setters and extracting that information would be a better idea here. What do YOU think?

Answer (score 3):

> A helper class that contains only the
>   logic to fill the object

is called a [Factory Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It seems that this is what you need.

Also, take a look at [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Where does this information come from? Is it hardcoded/consistent? Use the Object's [constructor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Is it variable or does it come from a datastore? Use the [DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

Comment: Here's a kickoff tutorial about the DAO pattern: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Answer (score 1):

Joshua Bloch discusses **Static Factories** and the **Builder** pattern in this [excerpt](http://www.ddj.com/java/208403883) from the second edition of his book *Effective Java*.

Comment: It seems to me that you answered my question. But it proves that the extraction/getting a reference logic should stay within the object. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the cited patterns are ways to impose an internally consistent object state. The manner in which this is achieved is an implementation detail. As your source is a DataStore, the DAO pattern suggested by BalusC is a way to minimize the coupling  mentioned in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last phrase: 'So I can call it a factory, but would it really be what they called "A Factory pattern"?'

IMHO, patterns are just food for thought. Don't worry too much if whatever you're doing fits the exact textbook definition (which is disputed anyway) or not. :-)